# SQL - matching similar records with same set of values in jumbled order

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a table with the following values in three columns

```
John Smith, Edward Jones, 4  
John Deer, Jane Deer, 2  
Edward Jones, John Smith, 4
```

I would like to have a query that recognizes the first and third records as similar, selecting only the first and second records and leaving the third out. I can easily do this when the values are in the same order, but I'm having trouble coming up with something that can discern similarity when the values are in arbitrary order like this. Any ideas?

[edited for clarity - this is a table with three columns]

Comment: Is that one or several columns?

Comment: what makes the first and the third record similar? the last column (number 4)?

Comment: @BeNdErR I think it is the fact that it contains the exact same values but in different order

Comment: DrCopyPaste is right - the values are the same, they are just in a jumbled order. This is what I would like to have a query to somehow recognize, filtering out all records with the same set of values past the first one.

Comment: My suggestion: write a function that takes 3 parameters, in that function you order those values alphabetically and produce a combined value (just concatenated/hash/or what have you) then you use that function to select distinct values from the table

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use case statements to put the name columns into a consistent order.  Something like

```
create table n( n1 varchar(20), n2 varchar(20), v int);

insert into n select "john", "edward",4;
insert into n select "john", "jane", 3;
insert into n select "edward","john",4;



select distinct
  case when n1>n2 then n1 else n2 end n1,
  case when n1>n2 then n2 else n1 end n2,
  v
from n
```